# ClassCastException trying to partition JSON messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, classcastexception

I am trying to write a custom Kafka Partitioner ( the logic is based on value not key )
The Value has a JSON string
**Example** of "Object value" = "{name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"}"

```
public class JsonPartitioner implements Partitioner {
public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
        int partitionNumber = 0;
        
        String jsonStringValue = (String)value;// this is giving exception
        jsonStringValue = jsonStringValue.toLowerCase(); 
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    }
}
```

**Error**
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String       at com.xxx.yyy.kafka.partitioner.JsonPartitioner.partition(JsonPartitioner.java:86) ~[JsonPartitioner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]

I am not sure , how to convert incoming Object to string then to json
looking for some help

Comment: In your own words, what kind of Object are you expecting to receive? Why should it be possible to convert it to a string at all, and what should the result look like (and why)? When you say the `value` "has a" JSON string, what exactly does that mean - do you mean that in the OOP sense (it's a field), or a colloquial sense (the exact type should be `java.lang.String`), or something else? What happens if you try to `System.out.println` it, for example?

Comment: Also, please [show a complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough), formatted as code.

Comment: added example of value .... "{name: \"John\", age: 31, city: \"New York\"}"

Comment: And what is the **type** of that value?

Comment: Just call toString on the value; if it's a string you'll get the value, if it's some other type you'll get, for your purpose, garbage.

Comment: Calling `toString()` on a `byte[]` will not do what is needed here.   And we know it is a `byte[]` from the exception message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Error java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

`[B` means `byte[]` : see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) for `Class.getName()`.  Ergo, you are trying to cast a `byte[]` to a `String`.  If you have a `byte[]` you can create a string from it using one of the `String` constructors.  By you can't **cast** a `byte[]` to a `String`.

Also beware that when you are creating a `String` from a `byte[]` you need to know and use the correct character encoding for the bytes.  If you use the wrong character encoding, you are liable to get garbage characters in the string.

This **might be** the correct way to do it ...

```
String jsonStringValue = new String((byte[]) value);  // this uses the platform
                                                      // default character encoding
```

Refer to the `String` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for other constructors that might be more appropriate.

Comment: I feel like the more appropriate way to handle this would be to use the StringDeserializer class built into Kafka, or if using JSON, ObjectMapper.readTree

Comment: I suggest you write an Answer to say that then.